# Branch.io Referral Link expiry

Tags: branch.io

How many days does a Branch link last?

Do I need to create again and again for the same set of parameters?

Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Branch doesn't delete data - so the referral link will last forever. And if you try to create one with the same set of parameters, they make sure to not duplicate links. Don't worry about storing locally- you just call getShortUrl and [branch.io](https://branch.io/) does the rest.